# Delete child objects/records in one-to-many relationship using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a parent-child (one-to-many) relationship between product & packages. one product can have multiple packages. In my 'Edit Product' jsp page I am allowing user to edit product & delete/add/edit any package. Now, on submitting the changes I am doing saveOrUpdate(product) in my controller method. What I am observing is that new packages are getting added in DB but the ones that are deleted by user hence not in the packages Set of Product are not getting deleted from DB. My hiberate configurations snippet is below. Am I missing something here?

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="author.vo.ProductVO" table="Product">
    <id name="ProductID" type="long">
            <column name="Product_ID" />
            <generator class="increment" />
     </id>
    <set name="packages" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="false">
    <key column="Product_ID" not-null="true" on-delete="cascade"/>
    <one-to-many class="author.vo.PackageVO" />
     </set>
```

Code for adding product

```
@Autowired
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

this.hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(prod);
```

Comment: You should provide the controller code!

Comment: controller code is too big to post here. Is there something specific you want to know?

Comment: i assume when the entities are removed from the set, you do flush the session? if not, that may be what you are missing.

Comment: aishwarya, I tried but still it's not working. I am using hibernateTemplate of spring framework to do saveOrUpdate(). I guess it creates a new Hibernate session every time. Probably, that could be the reason we might not need to flush it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "cascade delete orphan" to your xml config, also, why dont you try a simple situation first of all.

1. is a save working with a parent - child.
2. is a delete working with a parent - child.